# SQL запрос методами ActiveRecord Yii2

Tags: php, sql, yii2, activerecord

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT item.*
FROM item
  JOIN price ON price.item = item.id
  JOIN currency ON currency.id = price.currency
ORDER BY price.price * currency.course ASC
```

Надо чтобы он выдавал не простой массив массивов, а массив объектов класса `Item` унаследованного от `ActiveRecord` в Yii2.

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, существующий PHP-код.

Comment: Например: 
$posts = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT item.*
FROM item
  JOIN price ON price.item = item.id
  JOIN currency ON currency.id = price.currency
ORDER BY price.price * currency.course ASC)
->queryAll();

Так я получаю масив масивов

А мне нужно:
$item = Item::find()->all(); // так я все получу, а мне те що в запросе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод [ActiveRecord::findBySql()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#findBySql()-detail):

```
$items = Item::findBySql("
    SELECT item.*
    FROM item
      JOIN price ON price.item = item.id
      JOIN currency ON currency.id = price.currency
    ORDER BY price.price * currency.course ASC
")->all();
```

Хотя в данном конкретном случае вполне можно сделать выборку и через ActiveQuery

Comment: Спасибо, это я и спрашивал)( Как можно сделать выборку и через ActiveQuery? )